# laravel filter elequent data by where clause or reuse elequent data

Tags: laravel

I want to reuse laravel elequent data. I don't know that question is meaning full. so I will explain using bellow coding.
I want to get some data using bellow coding.

```
$pending = Case::where('user_id', $id)->where('status', 0)->paginate(20);
$approved = Case::where('user_id', $id)->where('status', 1)->paginate(20);
```

but I think it is not a efficient way.
so I use bellow codding instead above code.
first time get parent data to variable.

```
$cases = Case::where('user_id', $id);
```

after I try to filter child data from above variable using where clause.

```
$pending = $cases->where('status', 0)->paginate(20);
$approved = $cases->where('status', 1)->paginate(20);
```

after executing $pending has right data. but $approved not as I wish.
How can I do that. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing inefficient to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cases->where(...)` adds a where clause to the query, but it doesn't get executed until you call `paginate` (or `get` and other functions that use the result).

Your `$approved` query therefore basically has `WHERE status=0 AND status=1`, which will never work.

You could try copying `$cases` into another variable (i.e. `$approvedCases = $cases;`) but you're probably better off with your original code.